# I'm not able to create react app by "create-react-app"

Tags: node.js, json, node-modules, eslint, create-react-app

I'm not able to create react app by create-react-app and it gives me an error

[image]

Comment: Try removing all npm cache by typing: `npm cache clean --force` into the console.

Comment: Try these [steps to create a react project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122386/2873538)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `npx create-react-app`, be sure to have npm >= 5.2

Comment: thanks gigiz you really helped me in solving this issue, i was stuck in from past 2-3 hours and your solution made my life at that moment easier

Answer (score 0):

First install create-react-app globally

```
npm install create-react-app -g
```

Then run the following command

```
create-react-app app-name
```